# Getting objects using LINQ and stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a stored procedure that is returning data in this format:

```
EmployeeID | DepartmentID
---------------------
1 | 1
2 | 1
3 | 2
4 | 4
5 | 4
```

I'm getting the results like so:

```
List<spResult> results = DataContext.sp().ToList();
```

I'd like to get a list of Employees for a certain Department, based on the data returned from the stored procedure. Something like:

```
int departmentId = 1;

List<Employee> employees = (from e in DataContext.Employees
                            //where...
                            select e).ToList();
```

How do I format my where clause to get the EmployeeIDs from the result set that have the given DepartmentID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get a subset of keys:

```
var empKeys = results.Where(i => i.DepartmentID = departmentID);
```

And then use this list in the query like:

```
List<Employee> employees = (from e in DataContext.Employees
                            where empKeys.Contains(e.EmployeeID)
                            select h).ToList();
```

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
List<spResult> results = DataContext.sp().ToList();

int departmentId = 1;

var departmentEmployees = from de in results
                          where de.DepartmentId == departmentId
                          select de.EmployeeID;

List<Employee> employees = (from e in DataContext.Employees
                            where departmentEmployees.Contains(e.ID)                            
                            select e).ToList();
```

Comment: +1, but I think you need to put the departmentEmployees in an array or `List<int>`

Comment: @jeroenh - I don't think you need to do that in this case. Could be wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

You should also be able to do something like this:

```
List<Employee> employees = DataContext.Employees.Where(e => empKeys.Contains(e.EmployeeID)).ToList()
```